# Angular 4, convert from component to module

Tags: angular, module, routes

I have a component **DfqComponent** that I want to turn into a module, but it should keep its routing behavoir. These are the routes I want to keep, defined in the module **ProductionLineRoutingModule**, that has its own outlet:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'line', component: ProductionLineListComponent },
  { path: 'line/:name', component: ProductionLineDetailsComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'dfq', component: DfqComponent },
    // other modules planed
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dfq' }
  ]
}];
```

To turn **DfqComponent** to **DfqModule** and call it as before, I used the following routing in **DfqRoutingModule**:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'line/:name/dfq', component: DfqComponent }
];
```

This showed me the desired html (actually only simply the word DFQ), but in my opinion there are two drawbacks:
1. The outlet now is the primary outlet of the **AppComponent**.
2. The route definition is coupled with the **ProductionLineModule** ('***line/:name/dfq***' instead of '***dfq***').

So how can I achieve this?

The project actually looks like this:

[image: Project overview]

Answer (score 1):

The way I do that is through loadChildren. In the parent Routing

```
[{
    path: 'line/:name',
    loadChildren: './dfq/Dfq.module#DfqModule'
}]
```

And in the dfq routing

```
 [{ 
      path: 'dfq', component: DfqComponent
 }]
```

And on the DfqModule in imports

```
    RouterModule.forChild(dfqRoutes),
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to **elasticrash** it now works and the code files look clearly.

To remove the children[] array in ***ProductionLineRoutingModule*** and by adding multiple path definitions with the  loadChildren property did the trick. DfqModule and DfqRoutingModule already were ok.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'line', component: ProductionLineListComponent },
  { path: 'line/:name', component: ProductionLineDetailsComponent,
  loadChildren: '../masterdata/masterdata.module#MasterdataModule'
  },
  { path: 'line/:name', component: ProductionLineDetailsComponent,
  loadChildren: '../order/order.module#OrderModule'
  },
  { path: 'line/:name', component: ProductionLineDetailsComponent,
  loadChildren: '../dfq/dfq.module#DfqModule'
  }
];
```

There's on thing missing: How can I now set a default route, like 'dfq'?

Thanks!